# Laravel: where to put custom sql code; in models or some custom classes?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5, models, controllers

***[Situation]***

I must her-build a existing application where you can choose from a list of clients and generate csv lists.

The problem is that all the client have separate custom long Oracle:SQL queries with sub queries to build a dataset and then make a export file csv.

So.. normally I would work with LV:Models  where it interacts with DB-Views or tables in Oracle.

> This is now not possible because there are to many custom joins etc
>   and shared tables in the querys.

So.. to rebuild one by one in LV, I must have for the DB interaction a (DB)class where I can put the existing SQL (maybe adjust a little) and Use it in the Controllers/Some Models...

> Q: How must I set up the architect patron for the custom sql queries
>   classses.
>
> 1. In Models? but there is no direct db:view/table
> 2. Custom Class and use some LV:DB classes?

Who can point me in  the right direction?

p.n. there are about 20 custom old classes with large sql queries..

Regards.

M

Comment: I think you need to create Repository for model and add custom query in the repository

Comment: Thank you Naveed, But to make it clear for myself:
- there are no models possible because its all long custom sql-queries, I cant edit the DB, so is there possible to use like a shadow model with no attachment to the DB?

Comment: Yes Repository is same one. https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/ ...